# Chart.js Bar chart resizes again when revisiting the tab

Tags: chart.js

I'm using react-chartjs-2 wrappers `Pie` and `Bar` within Bootstrap Tab components like below.

```
<TabContent activeTab={activeTab}>
  <TabPane tabId='1'>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <div className='chart-container'>
          <Pie
            data={pieData}
            options={{...}}
         />
       </div>
     </Col>
   </Row>
 </TabPane>
 <TabPane tabId='2'>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <div className='chart-container'>
          <Bar
            data={barData}
            options={{...}}
         />
       </div>
     </Col>
   </Row>
 </TabPane>
</TabContent>
```

A part of the `options` object provided to the `Bar` instance is this.

```
responsive: true,
onResize: function(newChart, newSize) {                                     
    if (newSize.width < 768) {
        newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.display = false;
    } else {
        newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.display = true;
    }
},
legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
            if (chart.width < 768) {
                chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.display = false;
            }
        } 
    }   
}, ...
```

When the page is loaded initially the `Bar` instance takes up the whole container. However when I switch to the tab 1 with the `Pie` instance then to the tab 2 with the `Pie` instance the later resizes about half the size of the container. By the size the graph reduces to it might look like the `Bar` instance tried to display the X axis tick labels.

The `div.chart-container` css rules are

```
.chart-container {
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

The complete code is at https://github.com/ElAnonimo/job-fullstack/blob/master/client/src/components/Stats.js.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this. In the `Bar` chart `options`:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    ticks: {
      display: false,
      callback: function(value, index, values) {
        return `${value.date}, ${value.time}`;
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Though I would've thought `display: false` would turn off the ticks at the very creation (initialization) of the Bar chart still at the full screen size the ticks are there when the page first loads.

Comments or explanations are welcome.